# What is the difference between createSpeechRecognizer() and createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer()?

Tags: java, android, android-speech-api, android-12

The `createSpeechRecognizer()` method was added in API level 8. The `createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer()` method has been added in Android S. *But their descriptions are same (according to the official site)*. Can anyone clarify the difference between them? Is there any possibility in the near future of the `createSpeechRecognizer()` method being deprecated?

Comment: In the `SpeechRecognizer` class description, it says that _"The implementation of this API is likely to stream audio to remote servers to perform speech recognition"_. The name `createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer` sounds like a recognizer created by that method won't stream any data to a server - i.e. the recognition is performed on-device. That's just my guess though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Your guess seems very logical.

Comment: But if the recognition is performed on device, how can ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS occur? This error has also been added in Android S.

Comment: That doesn't automatically mean that the new error code is related to the new method.

Comment: Yeah, this seems logical too. Thanks man.